# CSS div increase height but don´t decrease it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had this behaivour once as a bug but this time I really want it as a feature and can´t produce it.

```
<div style="height: auto;">
   <div> 
      Variable Text, which is sometimes longer and sometimes shorter.
      It changes while runtime. 
   </div>
</div>
```

So I want that this block increases its height automaticly but never decreases  from the last maximum. So my only idea would be using Jquery and append the height on every change as min-height. But I´m sure I had this before.

Comment: i think not a bug, because the div get height of content in CSs, so yes i'll use jquery or any similar to make

Comment: I know its no bug, but I had this special behaiviour once in my code. But I cant reproduce it. There was a css way to do it and I hope someone now it.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in CSS alone. You can set `min-height` on the element to prevent it collapsing smaller, however this cannot be changed at runtime without using JS. Your question would be much clearer if you could give an example of the content in the `div`, as well as an outline of how it is updated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is exactly the actual code, I just provide with jquery a new text. In a project a while ago I had nearly the same situation and there it happened like I want this time. Anyway if you say its not possible I do it the jquery way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/x6otm6x2/

```js
setInterval(function(){
 var newHeight = $('div').height() + 100;
 $('div').css({
   minHeight: newHeight
  });
  console.log($('div').height())
}, 1000);
```

```css
div{
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

I think this example may help you. 
I have used a **setInterval** of **1000ms** to update the height of the **container div** and every time it's height increases by **100px**.

I don't know when you will increase the container div height so i have used setInterval. In your case setInterval will be replaced by **some function** may be.

Comment: Tank you, done nearly the same. Just I don't add 100 px every x seconds, I spimply set the min-height on height change to the actual height of the object. Anyway my focus is on a pure css solution.